# Stratification on the propensity score: How can I calculate the variance ratio?

Tags: r

I performed a stratification on the propensity score via the MatchIt package:

```
install.packages("MatchIt")
library(MatchIt)

# Stratification on the propensity score

stra <- matchit(treat ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = data.mc, , method = "subclass")
smry.stra <- summary(stra, standardize = TRUE)
data.stra <- match.data(stra)
```

Now I would like to calculate the variance ratio of the propensity scores between the treatment and the control group. Could I just calculate the variances for the total treatment and control group?

```
stra.ratio <- var(data.stra$distance[data.stra$treat == 1]) /
var(data.stra$distance[data.stra$treat == 0])
```

Or would I have to consider the strata and the weights of the strata somehow?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This seems to be more of a request for statistical advice. Perhaps you could include a link to a page that describes how a "variance ratio" (whatever that might be in the context of judging success in matching) _should_ be calculated if you want this to be a specific coding question.

Comment: After matching without stratification, e.g. Nearest Neighbor matching, the variance ratio gets calculated like this: ratio = variance treatment group / variance control group. I just did not know if and how i should consider the strata and the weights in the case of stratification on the propensity score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of the package, the description of the value `weights`:

> "Each matched control unit has weight proportional to the number of treatment units to which it was matched, and the sum of the control weights is equal to the number of uniquely matched control units.
>   "

This indicates to me that yes, we should take the weighted variance. It wouldn't surprise me if the weighted treatment variance is always equal to the weighted variance as the weights should always be one, but we will definitely see a difference in the control variance.

Here is a reproducible example using the data that came with the `MatchIt` package:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(SDMTools)

data(lalonde)

stra <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + married + nodegree, data = lalonde, method = "subclass")
data.stra <- match.data(stra) 
treatment <- data.stra[data.stra$treat == 1, ]
control <- data.stra[data.stra$treat == 0, ]
stra.ratio <- wt.var(treatment$distance, treatment$weights) / wt.var(control$distance, control$weights)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it like that and it worked perfectly!